# Sync offline JQuery Mobile form

Tags: php, html, jquery-mobile, offline

My name is Dimas and I work as a developer in a hospital.

I've developed a web form with JQuery Mobile which is accessed from an Android tablet. It sends data (text and FILES) to the server (PHP) and it's saved in a MySQL database.

This tablets are used by doctors that are visiting the patients in their homes. Some of these patients live in remote areas with very bad Internet connection, so I'm thinking on use HTML5 Offline feature to solve these situations.

I started reading about it but I'm newbie with this technology. I've some questions:

- Do you think this is the best/easiest solution?
- If I could save the form data in a local sqlite storage when the tablet is offline, how I could synchronize it with the data in MySQL server when the tablet become online?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Build a small HTML5 form that is hosted online and stores data offline if the app is not connected to internet. Once connected to internet it should sync data in DB.

Step 1
Here are the sample files and tutorial,
https://github.com/alexgibson/OfflineForm

Step 2
Build a simple form
Docors name
Patient's name
Description of test
<> <>

Step 3
Store this data offline

Step 4
Sync the data and display report

Comment: Thx for the answer, I will look at it although I was searching for a standard method (not a plugin/framework).